# Monitoring EditingStarted and EditingStopped in JTable with EditorDelegate

Tags: java, swing, jtable

When trying to monitor the start and stop of cell editing, I found the `DefaultCellEditor.EditorDelegate` class with the promising method `startCellEditing(EventObject anEvent)`. The 1st version of the code below had no
`MouseListener`; `startCellEditing(...)` never got fired. A look into the sources
showed why: The single line of the method reads `return true`.
 Since a `fireEditingStarted()` method doesn't exist, I added a `MouseListener` to
the editor component which listens for the edit initiating double click and then calls `startCellEditing(...)`. But the `MouseListener` doesn't get fired, too.
 So how to get `startCellEditing(...)` going?

P.S.:
I know that monitoring the start of an edit can be done by overriding `JTable`'s
`prepareEditor(...)`, but I'd still like to see what I am missing in the code.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.EventObject;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class MonitorEditingStartStopped extends JFrame {

  public MonitorEditingStartStopped() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(220, 150);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    String headers[] = {"Fruit", "Count", "Profit"};
    Object data[][] = {
        {"Apple", 6, -0.3},
        {"Banana", 3, 0.4},
        {"Cherry", 10, 1.},
        {"Date", -3, -1.}
      };

    DefaultTableModel model= new DefaultTableModel(headers, 0) {
      public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        Class<?> returnValue;
        if (getRowCount()>0 && getValueAt(0, column)!=null)
          returnValue= getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        else
          returnValue= Object.class;
        return returnValue;
      }
    };
    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
      model.addRow(data[i]);
    }
    JTable table= new JTable(model);
    JTextField tf= new JTextField(10);
    tf.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    StartStopEditor editor= new StartStopEditor(table, tf);
    TableColumnModel tcm= table.getColumnModel();
    tcm.getColumn(1).setCellEditor(editor);
    JScrollPane scrollPane= new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setVisible(true);
  }


  public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(MonitorEditingStartStopped::new);
  }


  class StartStopEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {
    public StartStopEditor(JTable table, JTextField tf) {
      super(tf);
      delegate= new EditorDelegate() {
        @Override
        public Object getCellEditorValue() {
          if (tf.getText().isBlank()) return Integer.valueOf(0);
          return Integer.valueOf(tf.getText());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean startCellEditing(EventObject anEvent) {
          int row= table.getSelectedRow();
          int column= table.getSelectedColumn();
          System.out.printf("started %d, %d%n", row, column);
          tf.setText(table.getValueAt(row, column).toString());
          return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean stopCellEditing() {
          System.out.printf("editing stopped %d%n", getCellEditorValue());
          return super.stopCellEditing();
        }
      };
      tf.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
          System.out.println("Click");
          if (e.getClickCount()!=2) return;
          delegate.startCellEditing(new EventObject(tf));
        }
      });
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: Cell editing isn't initialised by the editor component (ie the `JTextField`), the event comes from the `JTable` itself, the editor is queried via the `isCellEditable` method to determine if the editor can be started. I'm not sure I understand the point of using the `delegate` in this use case.  You could override the `getCellEditorValue` method directly as well as the `cancelCellEditing` and `stopCellEditing` methods. There's probably also away of just using a `JFormattedTextField` to achieve the desired result without the need for customising the `DefaultCellEditor`

Comment: Not sure the context of why you are doing what you are doing but maybe you can check out the [Table Cell Listener](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/). It handles the PropertyChangeEvent on a JTable to listen for the cell to start/stop editing.

Comment: @MadProgrammer getCellEditorValue() is fired on every click. So I followed your suggestion of a JFormattedTextField instead. Thank you.

Comment: @camickr I used your TableCellListener in another app and it works great. Thank you.

Comment: @both Has anybody of you an idea in what scenario the ```DefaultCellEditor.EditorDelegate```'s ```startCellEditing(EventObject anEvent)``` method is used and how?

Comment: I believe the event tells the editor how it was invoked (mouse, F2, typing). See: [Table Select All Editor](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/20/table-select-all-editor/). I'm guessing this method passed the event object to the editor.

Comment: I've never used the `DefaultCellEditor.EditorDelegate`s class (in 20+ years of working with Swing), so, no, I can't say

Comment: @camickr Thank you for your comment on
`DefaultCellEditor.EditorDelegate.startCellEditing(EventObject anEvent)` illustrated in Table Select All Editor. Remains the question: How can one fire `startCellEditing(EventObject anEvent)` in an extended `EditorDelegate`?

Answer (score 0):

**Implementing MadProgrammer's idea of using a JFormattedTextField**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.text.*; // DecimalFormat, DecimalFormatSymbols, NumberFormat.
import java.util.EventObject;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.*; // NumberFormatter.
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class MonitorEditingStartStoppedFTF extends JFrame {
  int row, column;
  JFormattedTextField ftf;

  public MonitorEditingStartStoppedFTF() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(220, 150);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    String headers[] = {"Fruit", "Count", "Profit"};
    Object data[][] = {
        {"Apple", 6, -0.3},
        {"Banana", 3, 0.4},
        {"Cherry", 10, 1.},
        {"Date", -3, -1.}
      };

    DefaultTableModel model= new DefaultTableModel(headers, 0) {
      public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        Class<?> returnValue;
        if (getRowCount()>0 && getValueAt(0, column)!=null)
          returnValue= getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        else
          returnValue= Object.class;
        return returnValue;
      }
    };
    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
      model.addRow(data[i]);

    JTable table= new JTable(model);
    NumberFormatter numFmt = new NumberFormatter(new DecimalFormat("#,###"));
    numFmt.setAllowsInvalid(false);
/*  Even if ftf is made final, if ftf is not a class variable, the compiler
    reports "variable ftf might not have been initialized" for the following two
    System.out.println(... ftf.getValue()).
    JFormattedTextField ftf= new JFormattedTextField(numFmt) {
*/      
    ftf= new JFormattedTextField(numFmt) {
      String groupingSep= ""+new DecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator();

      @Override
      protected void processFocusEvent(FocusEvent e) {
        String s= e.paramString();
        s= s.substring(0, s.indexOf(','));
        if (s.equals("FOCUS_GAINED")) {
          System.out.println("Editing starts "+ftf.getValue());
          row= table.getSelectedRow();
          column= table.getSelectedColumn();
          System.out.printf("Row/column %d/%d value: %s%n", row, column,
                        table.getValueAt(row, column));
        }
        else if (s.equals("FOCUS_LOST")) {
          System.out.println("Editing stopped "+ftf.getValue());
          s= table.getValueAt(row, column).toString().replace(groupingSep, "");
          System.out.printf("Row, column %d,%d value: %s%n%n", row, column, s);
          table.setValueAt(Integer.valueOf(s), row, column);
          ftf.setValue(Integer.valueOf(0));
        }
        super.processFocusEvent(e);
      }
    };
    ftf.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.RIGHT);
    DefaultCellEditor editor= new DefaultCellEditor(ftf);
    TableColumnModel tcm= table.getColumnModel();
    tcm.getColumn(1).setCellEditor(editor);
    JScrollPane scrollPane= new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setVisible(true);
  }


  public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(MonitorEditingStartStoppedFTF::new);
  }

}
```

===========================================================
**Using Camickr's TableCellListener class**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class MonitorEditingStartStoppedTCL extends JFrame {

  public MonitorEditingStartStoppedTCL() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(220, 150);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    String headers[] = {"Fruit", "Count", "Profit"};
    Object data[][] = {
            {"Apple", 6, -0.3},
            {"Banana", 3, 0.4},
            {"Cherry", 10, 1.},
            {"Date", -3, -1.}
          };

    DefaultTableModel model= new DefaultTableModel(headers, 0) {
      public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        Class<?> returnValue;
        if (getRowCount()>0 && getValueAt(0, column)!=null)
          returnValue= getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        else
          returnValue= Object.class;
        return returnValue;
      }
    };
    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
      model.addRow(data[i]);

    JTable table= new JTable(model);
    Action action= new AbstractAction() {
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        TableCellListener2 tcl= (TableCellListener2)e.getSource();
        if (tcl.getColumn()!=1) return;
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("EditingStarted")) {
          System.out.println("EditingStarted");
          System.out.println("Row   : " + tcl.getRow());
          System.out.println("Column: " + tcl.getColumn());
          System.out.println("Old   : " + tcl.getOldValue());
        }
        else {
          System.out.println("EditingStopped");
          System.out.println("Row   : " + tcl.getRow());
          System.out.println("Column: " + tcl.getColumn());
          System.out.println("New   : " + tcl.getNewValue());
          System.out.println();
        }
      }
    };
    TableCellListener2 tcl = new TableCellListener2(table, action, true);
    JScrollPane scrollPane= new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollPane); //, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setVisible(true);
  }


  public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(MonitorEditingStartStoppedTCL::new);
  }

}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.beans.*;

/*
 *  This class listens for changes made to the data in the table via the
 *  TableCellEditor. When editing is started, the value of the cell is saved
 *  When editing is stopped the new value is saved. When the oold and new
 *  values are different, then the provided Action is invoked.
 *
 *  The source of the Action is a TableCellListener instance.

 *  This is a slightly extended version of Rob Camick's original which can be found on
https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/07/table-cell-listener/
 *  The extension consists of an additional constructor having a boolean as
 *  third parameter "performActionOnEditingStarted".
 *  The command strings "EditingStarted" and "EditingStopped" are defined for
 *  the corresponding ActionEvent. Thus in the actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
 *  method of the Action parameter one can check the current action e. g. with
 *  if (e.getActionCommand().equals("EditingStarted")) {...}
 */
public class TableCellListener2 implements PropertyChangeListener, Runnable
{
    private boolean performActionOnEditingStarted;
    private JTable table;
    private Action action;

    private int row;
    private int column;
    private Object oldValue;
    private Object newValue;

    /**
     *  Create a TableCellListener.
     *
     *  @param table   the table to be monitored for data changes
     *  @param action  the Action to invoke when cell data is changed
     */
    public TableCellListener2(JTable table, Action action)
    {
        this.table = table;
        this.action = action;
        this.table.addPropertyChangeListener( this );
    }

    /**
     *  Create a TableCellListener.
     *
     *  @param table   the table to be monitored for data changes
     *  @param action  the Action to invoke when cell data is changed
     *  @param performActionOnEditingStarted
     *         If true, the action is also fired on 'EditingStarted'
     */
    public TableCellListener2(JTable table, Action action,
                 boolean performActionOnEditingStarted)
    {
        this.table = table;
        this.action = action;
        this.performActionOnEditingStarted=
                        performActionOnEditingStarted;
        this.table.addPropertyChangeListener( this );
    }

    /**
     *  Create a TableCellListener with a copy of all the data relevant to
     *  the change of data for a given cell.
     *
     *  @param row  the row of the changed cell
     *  @param column  the column of the changed cell
     *  @param oldValue  the old data of the changed cell
     *  @param newValue  the new data of the changed cell
     */
    private TableCellListener2(JTable table, int row, int column, Object oldValue, Object newValue)
    {
        this.table = table;
        this.row = row;
        this.column = column;
        this.oldValue = oldValue;
        this.newValue = newValue;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the column that was last edited
     *
     *  @return the column that was edited
     */
    public int getColumn()
    {
        return column;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the new value in the cell
     *
     *  @return the new value in the cell
     */
    public Object getNewValue()
    {
        return newValue;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the old value of the cell
     *
     *  @return the old value of the cell
     */
    public Object getOldValue()
    {
        return oldValue;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the row that was last edited
     *
     *  @return the row that was edited
     */
    public int getRow()
    {
        return row;
    }

    /**
     *  Get the table of the cell that was changed
     *
     *  @return the table of the cell that was changed
     */
    public JTable getTable()
    {
        return table;
    }
//
//  Implement the PropertyChangeListener interface
//
    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e)
    {
        //  A cell has started/stopped editing

        if ("tableCellEditor".equals(e.getPropertyName()))
        {
            if (table.isEditing())
                processEditingStarted();
            else
                processEditingStopped();
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Save information of the cell about to be edited
     */
    private void processEditingStarted()
    {
        //  The invokeLater is necessary because the editing row and editing
        //  column of the table have not been set when the "tableCellEditor"
        //  PropertyChangeEvent is fired.
        //  This results in the "run" method being invoked

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater( this );
    }
    /*
     *  See above.
     */
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        row = table.convertRowIndexToModel( table.getEditingRow() );
        column = table.convertColumnIndexToModel( table.getEditingColumn() );
        oldValue = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);
        newValue = null;
        if (performActionOnEditingStarted) {
            TableCellListener2 tcl = new TableCellListener2(
                getTable(), getRow(), getColumn(), getOldValue(), getNewValue());
            ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(
                tcl,
                ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
                "EditingStarted");
            action.actionPerformed(event);
        }
    }

    /*
     *  Update the Cell history when necessary
     */
    private void processEditingStopped()
    {
        newValue = table.getModel().getValueAt(row, column);

        //  The data has changed, invoke the supplied Action

        if (! newValue.equals(oldValue))
        {
            //  Make a copy of the data in case another cell starts editing
            //  while processing this change

            TableCellListener2 tcl = new TableCellListener2(
                getTable(), getRow(), getColumn(), getOldValue(), getNewValue());

            ActionEvent event = new ActionEvent(
                tcl,
                ActionEvent.ACTION_PERFORMED,
                "EditingStopped");
            action.actionPerformed(event);
        }
    }
}
```

Last not least my original solution with least code:
**JTable.prepareEditor(...)**

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;

public class MonitorEditingStartStoppedPrepare extends JFrame {

  public MonitorEditingStartStoppedPrepare() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(220, 150);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);

    String headers[] = {"Fruit", "Count", "Profit"};
    Object data[][] = {
            {"Apple", 6, -0.3},
            {"Banana", 3, 0.4},
            {"Cherry", 10, 1.},
            {"Date", -3, -1.}
          };

    DefaultTableModel model= new DefaultTableModel(headers, 0) {
      public Class<?> getColumnClass(int column) {
        Class<?> returnValue;
        if (getRowCount()>0 && getValueAt(0, column)!=null)
          returnValue= getValueAt(0, column).getClass();
        else
          returnValue= Object.class;
        return returnValue;
      }
    };
    for (int i=0; i<data.length; i++)
      model.addRow(data[i]);

    JTable table= new JTable(model) {
      public void editingStopped(ChangeEvent e) {
        int row= getSelectedRow();
        int column= getSelectedColumn();
        super.editingStopped(e);
        System.out.println("Editing stopped "+ getValueAt(row, column));
      }

      public Component prepareEditor(TableCellEditor editor, int row,
                                int column) {
        System.out.println("Editing started "+ getValueAt(row, column));
        return super.prepareEditor(editor, row, column);
      }
    };
    JScrollPane scrollPane= new JScrollPane(table);
    add(scrollPane); //, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    setVisible(true);
  }


  public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(MonitorEditingStartStoppedPrepare::new);
  }

}
```

The use case is the following:
I have an editable column of integers which is initially blank - in fact it
contains 0 values rendered as blank.
If the user wants to enter some value in that column, I display a default value
in the cell when the user starts editing. When editing stops, I update other
cells of the corresponding row.

Comment: I get a NumberFormatException when I attempt to edit a value in the  "Count" column. Probably because your replace(...) statement replaces a "." instead of a ","? Still not sure what problem you are attempting to solve. I think I get the same results even without overriding any of the processFocusEvent method of the formatted text field.

Comment: No, not like this - stop "trying" to do the cell editors job and just let it do it's job for you. If you have some rule around the format of the cell, that would be better managed by the `TableModel#setValue` method

Comment: @camickr Most countries in Europe use the point as 1000s separator. I just updated the code to make it more international and also described the use case.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I didn't have any formatting in mind. But since JFormattedTextField inserts 1000s separators as default and since any editing converts the cell's data into a String, I wanted to make sure that the column remains pure integer.

Comment: Override the `getCellEditorValue` method and return result `JFormattedTextField#getValue` - in it's basic sense

Comment: @MadProgrammer I tried to override `getCellEditorValue` but still get null values. Would you kindly have a look at the test case I added to my last post?

Comment: If I get rid of the `processFocusEvent` method, it seems to work just fine for me - applying the value to getting the value from the component is the role of the `TableCellEditor`, just let it do it's job

Comment: *default and since any editing converts the cell's data into a String,* - no it doesn't. It should return a value based on the column class. That is why I'm questioning the entire code. *I have an editable column of integers which is initially blank* - and that would be your problem. Also, note that your MRE doesn't demonstrate this since all the columns have a value (so how would we guess this?). Maybe a better solution is to have 0 as the default value. Then use a custom renderer to display the value as a blank. Then you won't have a problem with the editor converting the object to a string.

Comment: Also, your getColumnClass method would be wrong. You are always assuming the first row will NOT contain a blank. I would be better to simply return the class based on the column, not the data.

Comment: Well, currently I am only trying to implement your suggestions in the MRE here and I am not reporting errors of code elsewhere. - My objective, however, is still to be signalled when editing starts and when it stops, as denoted in the post's title. In my view, dropping the `processFocusEvent` method would eliminate all possibility of signalling. - I replaced the testcase with code making use of Camickr's slightly extended TableCellListener.